# How can I tell whether a Java class is an instance of a class or interface that might not be on the classpath?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, classpath, instanceof

I'm working with a multi-module Gradle Spring Boot application that has a shared "library" module with common functionality shared among the other modules.  One of the classes in the module is doing some custom logic if a value passed in is an instance of a given class from another library.

```java
if (methodArgument instanceof OtherLibraryClass) {
  doSomethingWithOtherLibraryClass((OtherLibraryClass) methodArgument);
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to make that other library an optional dependency, so only the modules that actually use that library need to pull it in:

```groovy
dependencies {
  compileOnly 'com.example:my-optional-dependency:1.0.0'
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to do the `instanceof` check against a class that might not even be on the classpath.  Is there a way to do this instance check without needing the class on the classpath?  I've got the following manual approach (using [`ClassUtils.hierarchy`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ClassUtils.html#hierarchy-java.lang.Class-org.apache.commons.lang3.ClassUtils.Interfaces-) from [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) to get all superclasses & superinterfaces:

```java
    if (isInstance(methodArgument, "com.example.OtherLibraryClass")) {
      doSomethingWithOtherLibraryClass((OtherLibraryClass) methodArgument);
    }
  }

  private static boolean isInstance(Object instance, String className) {
    if (instance == null) {
      return false;
    }
    return StreamSupport.stream(
            ClassUtils.hierarchy(obj.getClass(), ClassUtils.Interfaces.INCLUDE).spliterator(),
            false
    ).anyMatch(c -> className.equals(c.getName()));
  }
```

This approach feels a bit heavyweight, as it needs to iterate over every supertype each time.  This feels like something that might already be provided, such as by the Spring or Spring Boot frameworks the application is already using.

Is there a more straightforward and/or performant approach to determining whether a given object is an instance of a particular class that might not be on the classpath?

Comment: What about having two versions of your shared library? The shared library as it is actually and a second version without the features that you want to exclude.

Comment: Are you looking for `java.util.ServiceLoader`? or `Class.getName().equals(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to reflectively load the `Class` object and using that for the instance check, returning false if the class is not on the classpath:

```java
private static boolean isInstance(Object instance, String className) {
    try {
        return Class.forName(className).isInstance(instance);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The class could be cached based on its name for future calls if desired to avoid the overhead of the reflective class creation/lookup on each check.